# Hibernate get without explicit Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, transactions

I am trying to understand the reason behind using transaction in the following piece of code retrieved from Hibernate Documentation.

```
Session session1 = factory1.openSession();
Transaction tx1 = session1.beginTransaction();
Cat cat = session1.get(Cat.class, catId);
tx1.commit();
session1.close();
//reconcile with a second database
Session session2 = factory2.openSession();
Transaction tx2 = session2.beginTransaction();
session2.replicate(cat, ReplicationMode.LATEST_VERSION);
tx2.commit();
session2.close();
```

What I understand from this [JBOSS Docs](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-13953) that even though if I dont use a transaction that should not be a problem in this case. Can some body educate me more on this in terms of isolation etc . what actually happens if we do or dont use transaction in the above scenario

*Working nontransactionally with Hibernate
Look at the following code, which accesses the database without transaction boundaries:*

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();   
session.get(Item.class, 123l);   
session.close();
```

*By default, in a Java SE environment with a JDBC configuration, this is what happens if you execute this snippet:

1. A new Session is opened. It doesn’t obtain a database connection at this point.
2. The call to get() triggers an SQL SELECT. The Session now obtains a JDBC Connection from the connection pool. Hibernate, by default, immediately turns off the autocommit mode on this connection with setAutoCommit(false). This effectively starts a JDBC transaction!
3. The SELECT is executed inside this JDBC transaction. The Session is closed, and the connection is returned to the pool and released by Hibernate — Hibernate calls close() on the JDBC Connection. What happens to the uncommitted transaction?   The answer to that question is, “It depends!” The JDBC specification doesn’t say anything about pending transactions when close() is called on a connection. What happens depends on how the vendors implement the specification. With Oracle JDBC drivers, for example, the call to close() commits the transaction! Most other JDBC vendors take the sane route and roll back any pending transaction when the JDBC Connection object is closed and the resource is returned to the pool. Obviously, this won’t be a problem for the SELECT you’ve executed, but look at this variation:*

Answer (score 0):

If its one statement you wouldnt tell the difference, but if you are trying to do ***multiple statements*** in a ***single*** transaction you would see what they are for.

If you open a transaction and attempt multiple `CRUD` operations and one fails, you can roll back the transaction and pretty much go back to a previous state within the transaction (even before everything).

On the other hand, if you dont open a transaction, its opened and closed implicitly every time you use a statement so if you do multiple `CRUD` operations and one fails, there is no way to roll back the data and you will end up with bad data.

Side note : this doesnt really matter for ***select*** statements

Comment: Edward , Thanks for replying .I understand the Multiple statements or CRUD operation point. But If you see the documentation for even single select txn is used.

Comment: On a select statement, to my knowledge, it doesnt really matter. It only matters on statements that modify the DB. Its probably done to keep the code uniform on how to access the DB. Or maybe thinking about the future since you may add code on that method to modify the DB after querying it later on.

Comment: @AbhijitMazumder Most databases require that everything is executed in a transaction. And databases that do allow doing it without a transaction, will internally wrap the statement in a transaction. That is because transactions are fundamental to how a database works when it tries to guarantee the ACID properties.

Comment: Totally understand that point. Trying to understand if it makes any difference using explicit transaction